# How to change the height of UITableViewCell within that cell with UITableView with automatic dimension?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableviewautomaticdimension

So far I tried:

```
@IBOutlet weak var requestDateButtonBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

requestDateButtonBottomConstraint.constant = sender.selected ? 0 : 260
```

I also tried frame approach:

```
var cellFrame = self.frame
cellFrame.size.height = sender.selected ? 44 : 260
self.frame = cellFrame
```

No one is working...

Comment: You should take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights almost everything is covered here about dynamic `UITableViewCell` height.

Comment: So you want to change something INSIDE your cell to the size of your cell,  calculated with UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

just return actual height in

`UITableViewDelegate`

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (something) {
        return 260.0
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
}
```